# Converting int to byte(32)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, numbers, converters

i am trying to convert a 32bit number to and integer and vice veras

is there an easy way to?

maybe something like

```
Dim bin As New Byte(32)
bin = CType(CType(TextBox_B10.Text, Integer), Byte(32))
```

Comment: 32 *bit* or 32 *byte*?  Bit and byte are not the same thing.  And `Integer` is already a 32 bit number.

Comment: now that i am looking i want it in bit..
not sets of 8 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)`, which will return an array of 4 bytes.

Comment: how would i get this into BITS? like 32 individual bits?

Comment: You can use bitwise operations to extract the value of any bit from a byte.  Or, use the `BitArray` class.